# How to filter a list of generic objects

Tags: vb.net, list, linq-to-objects

I have find the code to implement a SortableBindingList that extends of BindingList and it theoretically let sort and filter a list of generic objects.
It works perfectly sorting the list but I can not get filtering.

The filter code is as follows

```
       Protected Sub UpdateFilter()
        _isSorted = False 'remove sort.
        Try
            'We filter on the entire collection
            Dim filtered = _originalData.AsQueryable()

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_filter) Then filtered = filtered.Where(_filter)

            Dim filteredResult = filtered.ToList()
            Items.Clear()

            If filteredResult IsNot Nothing AndAlso filteredResult.Count > 0 Then
                For Each tItem As T In filtered
                    Items.Add(tItem)
                Next
            End If
        Catch
            'Reset the list
            Items.Clear()
            For Each tItem As T In _originalData
                Items.Add(tItem)
            Next

            'Rethrow the error
            Throw
        Finally
            OnListChanged(New ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1))
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The problem is that the following example receive like a filter a string in the clause where but the compile trhow an error since it wait a function
I don't know how to resolve this

Sorry if you do not understand well. I do not speak English well

Comment: The `Where` clause expects a `Function(item as T)` (where T is the type of the items in `_originalData`) that returns a `Boolean` result. You will need function that can parse `_filter` and process the logic it represents to a `Boolean` result.  That is not an easy task.  An easier way (but still a fair amount of work)is to present the user with a form that allows them to select a property defined on `T`, an comparison operator to apply, and enter a value to compare the property against.  Doing it this way limits the possibilities that need to be considered in the expression evaluation code.

Comment: Continued.. If you are familiar with MS Excel, look at how they handle defining a custom AutoFilter by presenting a dialog box with drop-downs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a predicate. I hope this example will guide you.

```
Private Function AddFilter(list As List(Of String), filter As Func(Of String, Integer, Boolean)) As List(Of String)
    Dim l As IEnumerable(Of String) = Nothing
    If Not IsNothing(filter) Then
        l = list.Where(filter)
    End If
    Return l.ToList
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim A As New List(Of String) From {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
    Dim predicate As Func(Of String, Integer, Boolean) = Function(str, index) str.StartsWith("M")
    Dim FilteredList = AddFilter(A, predicate)
    For Each s As String In FilteredList
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer in some post that recommend this.

You can use Dynamic Linq:

Dim filter As String = "property1>10 and property2 like 'anystring' or property3<=25".

Dim results = Elements.Where(filter).

But I don't know how to use dinamic linq